# How to plot CDF using two dataset in R

Tags: r, plot, power-law

I'm trying to plot the below dataset using plot function. Im unable to plot both the graphs in same plot.

Using the dataset I tried to plot the graph.

```
m_bs = conpl$new(sample_data1$V1)
m_eq = conpl$new(sample_data2$V1)

est = estimate_xmin(m_bs, xmax=5e+5)
est_eq = estimate_xmin(m_eq, xmax=Inf)

m_bs$setXmin(est_bs)
m_eq$setXmin(est_eq)

plot(m_bs)
lines(m_bs)
d = plot(m_eq, draw =FALSE)
points(d$x, d$y, col=2)
lines(m_eq,col=2,lwd=2)
```

I got the below graph, it only shows one graph. Sorry for posting the question again I didnt get proper answer earlier post.

[image]

Comment: It seems to me you get both plots but because you plot the one with the smaller x axis range first the data from the other data frame is outside the plotting region. You can see one red dot from the second plot. Try setting xlim on your first plot so it matches the scale of both datasets

Comment: You should post a reproducible example, too. You call functions not in base R. What packages did you use (i.e. add the `library` calls to your post).

Comment: i only imported library('poweRlaw')

Answer (score 1):

I looked up the source code of the `plot` function used by `poweRlaw` and modified it:

```
lines_ <- function (x, y, ...) 
{
  .local <- function (x, cut = FALSE, draw = TRUE, ...) 
  {
    xmin = x$getXmin()
    cut_off = cut * xmin
    x_values = x$dat
    if (!cut) 
      x$setXmin(min(x_values))
    y = dist_data_cdf(x, lower_tail = FALSE, xmax = max(x_values) + 1)
    cut_off_seq = (x_values >= cut_off)
    x_axs = x_values[cut_off_seq]
    if (is(x, "discrete_distribution")) 
      x_axs = unique(x_axs)
    x$setXmin(xmin)
    x = x_axs
    if (draw) 
      lines(x, y, ...)
    invisible(data.frame(x = x, y = y))
  }
  .local(x, ...)
}

#----------------------------------------------------------

points_ <- function (x, y, ...) 
{
  .local <- function (x, cut = FALSE, draw = TRUE, ...) 
  {
    xmin = x$getXmin()
    cut_off = cut * xmin
    x_values = x$dat
    if (!cut) 
      x$setXmin(min(x_values))
    y = dist_data_cdf(x, lower_tail = FALSE, xmax = max(x_values) + 1)
    cut_off_seq = (x_values >= cut_off)
    x_axs = x_values[cut_off_seq]
    if (is(x, "discrete_distribution")) 
      x_axs = unique(x_axs)
    x$setXmin(xmin)
    x = x_axs
    if (draw) 
      points(x, y, ...)
    invisible(data.frame(x = x, y = y))
  }
  .local(x, ...)
}
```

The functions `lines_` and `points_`

- draw the same graph as the `plot` function of the `poweRlaw` package, but
- behave like the standard `lines` and `points` functions in that they don't destroy the current graph.

First `m_bs` and 'm_eq' separately:

```
> plot(m_bs, lwd=9, col="black")

> lines_(m_bs, lwd=5, col="green")
```

[image]

```
> plot(m_eq, lwd=9, col="black")

> lines_(m_eq, lwd=5, col="blue")
```

[image]

The x-ranges of these to graphs do not overlap. Hence `xlim` has to be chosen appropriately to show both graphs in the same picture.

```
> plot( m_eq, lwd=8, col="black",
+       xlim=c(min(m_bs$dat,m_eq$dat),max(m_bs$dat,m_eq$dat)))

> lines_(m_eq, lwd=5, col="blue")

> points_(m_bs,lwd=8,col="black")

> lines_(m_bs, lwd=5, col="green")
>
```

[image]